# win32 raw keyboard input remove autorepeat

Tags: c++, winapi, directx

So the problem at hand is pretty much the following:
[Windows key repeat settings affecting Raw Input messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36985029/windows-key-repeat-settings-affecting-raw-input-messages)

Although this might be a duplicate then, there is no answer provided, so here it goes:

1. I am under the impression that e.g. for FPS game development, one should use raw input. The problem then however, is that the input is not so raw after all and includes a delay (for a continuous keydown) and only after that initial delay a continuous key press, that is continuous flow of WM_INPUT messages. When using DirectInput (which is deprecated), I do not have those problems. Is there a way to achieve the same thing using only raw input? To be clear, what I want is that, if I press a key continuously, I continuously get WM_INPUT messages without the initial delay caused by autorepeat.
   I am using the raw input standard read, not the buffered one (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645546(v=vs.85).aspx)
2. Where is the difference between the aforementioned standard raw input reading and the buffered one?

Comment: I don't know about win32 raw input specifically - but usually, you'd just ignore the keydown event if you already knew the key was down.

Comment: You generally shouldn't use Win32 RAW input for anything but mouse. See [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) and the ``Keyboard`` and ``Mouse`` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DirectInput is an outdated, async abstraction layer, that does exactly the same thing: processes raw input. It is not recommended to use it unless you need to support joystick or anything legacy, for gamepads XInput is being recommended.

Windows is not a real time OS, the best option is to stick to WM_INPUT messages. This requires maintaining an array of key states (bool keyState[256]) and basing your logic as if(keyState[VK_BACKSPACE] == true){}.
If you want to also catch the press start and release events, you will have to maintain an array of last key state, and analyzing WM_INPUT check for the change, and produce the press start event only if last state of key was false and WM_INPUT message says key is pressed now.

The other option is to use GetAsyncKeyState to manually check all the input regularly. But that will leave you without the ability to catch key press if it happened between your two calls for GetAsyncKeyState. The documentation of the function says that the lower bit tells exactly that, but that bit is shared among all applications and can be reset by other app, which is sad.

If I understand you correctly, what you want is just the momentary key state, which can be easily obtained through helper classes like [Keyboard](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Keyboard), it does not use WM_INPUT though, so a minor latency may occur due to window check layer.

```
auto kb = keyboard->GetState();

if (kb.Back)
    // Backspace key is down, with no delay of waiting for key repeat
```

Comment: Didn't know about the Mouse and Keyboard classes from the toolkit. With those it works flawlessly!